# Cannot resolve com.palantir.docker.compose:docker-compose-rule-junit4:0.32.0

Tags: java, docker, maven, docker-compose, maven-dependency

Trying to drag this dependency from maven but get error, what could be the issue?
Cannot resolve com.palantir.docker.compose:docker-compose-rule-junit4:0.32.0

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.palantir.docker.compose</groupId>
    <artifactId>docker-compose-rule-junit4</artifactId>
    <version>0.32.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

The packet did not exist in maven central repo  https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, so I had to add extra one.

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>Palantir</id>
        <url>https://dl.bintray.com/palantir/releases/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```